# Modify uilabel from a view to other - iphone sdk

Tags: xcode, label, uilabel, tableview, transition

I have TableViewController & DetailViewController.
I'd like to modify one label named 'label' in DetailViewController.

TableViewController.h :

```
@interface CodexTableView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource>
{
 NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    DetailViewController *vc;



}
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *vc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;

@end
```

And an extract of my TableViewController.m :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

vc.label.text = @"bonjour";


//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

dvController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;
```

}

But it doesn't works.
Someone know the error ? 
Please help me.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You mix up two variables for your detail view controller. Remove the `dvController` one and only work with your `vc` property, like so:

```
vc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[vc label] setText:@"bonjour"];
```

Make `label` a property of your detail view controller and have it point at your onscreen label.

Comment: hi, Thanks for informations but I have the same error again, it doesn't works.
I try to use the same variable ... the result is the same as last time...

Comment: Well, you could give your detail view controller a property that is an `NSString *` and set it from the place where I told you to set @"bonjour". Then in your detail view controller, in the `viewDidLoad` method (when you are certain that your onscreen label and other views are ready) you could get your NSString * and assign it to the text-value of your label.
Writing from the top of my head here, so no copy-and-paste ready code, sorry.